# Do I pay for default construction here and if so can I avoid it

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

In the case where T is expensive to construct I'd like to know if I pay for default construction in the following case (I think I do)

```
std::function< T() > make_t;
std::vector< T > t( 100000 );
std::generate( t.begin(), t.end(), make_T );
```

If I do have to pay for it can I avoid it?  I wanted to write something like

```
std::function< T() > make_t;
std::vector< T > t;
t.reserve( 100000 );
std::generate( t.begin(), t.end(), make_T );
```

But that does not work because it does not move t.end() to the end of what is reserved.  Is the following safe/advisable/correct?

```
std::function< T() > make_t;
std::vector< T > t;
t.reserve( 100000 );
std::generate( t.begin(), t.begin() + 100000, make_T );
```

I also thought I might be able to use a back_inserter but the interface is right for what I have (I have a function that generates a new T object every time it is accessed not a pair of iterators to a range).

C++0x solutions preferred to C++03 solutions (i.e., ones that leverage the new standard if there's  a better way to do it there) preferred to solution that need to use boost.

Comment: `reserve` does not do what you think - your code is broken as it dereferences undefined iterators!

Comment: Is `T` cheap to move? With C++0x move semantics perhaps the situation isn't as bad as you think. Using `reserve` plus back-inserter, I suppose. Hey, does C++0x have a "back-emplacer"?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: Or did you mean is there an std::emplace_inserter which I can't find if it exists.

Comment: Yes, I meant the iterator version for use in algorithms. I haven't thought about this though and I don't know if that even makes sense.

Comment: The actual question is: If T is expensive to construct, is making 100k cheap copies of T meaningful (and safe!) in any way? The answer is no. If a container can be initialized cheaply with 100k instances of T, this means that either T must have some internal "not initialized" flag, or it means that T must only have POD data. If T::T acquires resources (memory, files, handles, whatever), it is terribly bad luck to let 100k instances control (and possibly free!) these. So, if constructing T is expensive and a trivial constructor is no-go, there is hardly a C++/stdlib way to cheat around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::function< T() > make_t;
std::vector< T > t;
int const count = 100000;
t.reserve( count );
std::generate_n( std::back_inserter(t), count, make_T );
```

`std::back_inserter` is in `<iterator>`.

Comment: Hey, have you heard of an "emplace" version of the back-inserter?

Comment: @Kerrek: is there any point? `emplace` constructs directly into the container from a list of constructor parameters, but since `make_T` returns an object, you'd only be emplacing using the copy- or move- constructor anyway. So just make sure the type T is efficiently movable and `push_back(T&&)` should do just as well as a hypothetical `emplace_iterator` would. I think. After inlining maybe both can eliminate the temporary, assuming no side-effects, but I think the only way to formally forbid the temporary is to ditch `make_T` and emplace *with no arguments*.

Comment: @Kerrek There isn't any. It breaks the symmetry but not much functionality is lost -- Steve covered it already. (I'm in chat if you want to discuss it.)

Comment: Sorry, no arguments is wrong, I should have said with whatever arguments `make_T` constructs its return value from. That is, `t.reserve(count); for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) t.emplace_back(whatever_make_T_does);`. But I got a bit carried away, the questioner isn't even asking how to eliminate the temporary, and `generate_n` already solves the question of how to fit `back_inserter` to the situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix your second solution with the use of the `std::back_inserter` iterator, which does the `push_back` for you:

```
std::vector< T > t;
t.reserve(100000);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(t), 100000, make_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will pay for default construction in the case you were afraid of.  You should prove it to yourself by inspecting the generated assembly code on your particular platform, though.

I'd make the vector hold `shared_ptr<T>` rather than plain `T`, then the rest is easy.  It also facilitates moving the objects around later if you turn out to need that.

Comment: "by inspecting the generated assembly code" - typically quicker to use a couple `std::cout`s or a breakpoint....